# Slick Slider is not working with Loop in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, slick.js

I am trying to use a slick slider it's working fine outside the loop but not working in foreach loop.
Here is the code without loop

```
      <div style="width: 120%; margin: 0 -10%;left: 0;  right:0;">
      <section class="center slider">
        <div>
          <img src="http://dev9.hostriplex.com/clearcube/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/CD5014_Front_view.png?text=1">
        </div>
        <div>
          <img src="http://dev9.hostriplex.com/clearcube/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/CD5012_Front_view-200.png?text=2">
        </div>
        <div>
          <img src="http://dev9.hostriplex.com/clearcube/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/CD5014_rear_view.png?text=3">
        </div>
        <div>
          <img src="http://dev9.hostriplex.com/clearcube/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/CD5014_Front_view.png?text=4">
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
    <script src="slick.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">

     $(document).on('ready', function() {   

        $(".center").slick({
        dots: true,
        infinite: true,
        centerMode: true,
        slidesToShow: 3,
        slidesToScroll: 1
      });

     });

 </script>
```

It's working perfectly fine.

But when I try to convert it in the loop it stops working. Below is the code with a loop.

```
 <div style="width: 120%; margin: 0 -10%;left: 0;  right:0;">
 <section class="center slider">
 <?php foreach ($thumbs_array as $thumbnail) { //Returning 3 iterations
 echo '<div><img src="' . $thumbnail . '"></div>';
 } ?>
</section>
</div>
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Is there any javascript error you are getting?

Comment: No javascript error. The console is clear.

Comment: Are the images being dispayed? What exactly about this 'doesn't work'?

Comment: inspect and check if the path of the images rendered correctly.

Comment: This is the output with loop https://prnt.sc/pzhlij and this is without loop https://prnt.sc/pzhml2 which is working fine.

Comment: Images are loading in inspect.

Comment: Please show an example of the HTML that renders out from the PHP loop.

Comment: `slidesToShow: 3` and your returning iterations are also 3. So, slick slider initializing but not scrolling. If your iterations are more than 3, it'll scroll.

Comment: Thank you so much @asfan Shaikh. That was the issue. Images less than 3 causing the problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to change $(document).on('ready'.... to
 `$(window).on('load', function(){`

It will first load all the content of page and then it will execute your script.